# Loading .NET assemblies from a network share

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, code-access-security

I've created an assembly that needs to run from a network share for use with AutoCAD.  The code runs fine when called from AutoCAD on the local PC, but when called from the network share it throws a `System.Security.SecurityException` exception.  I've done some research and tried setting the network share to full trust using `caspol` but it still doesn't work.  Looking at the trace, it seems to error when calling a method from one of the AutoCAD asssemblies also present on the share.

How can I set it so that all the assemblies on the share run?

Comment: Does any of the information here help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507669/trusting-an-assembly-located-on-a-network-share

Comment: Provide more information and possibly a test case. This is tricky. Is the network share trusted?

Comment: @reuben thanks but it doesnt.  Ive set the share to full trust and it makes no difference

Comment: @TomTom.  I used caspol to set the share to full trust but it didnt make any difference.

Comment: This doesn't necessarily solve the root problem, but is it a hard requirement that the assemblies be loaded from the share? Is it possible to have the first library loaded from the share arrange for / copy all of its dependencies to a temp folder on the local PC, and load the local copies?

Answer (score 0):

Copy it locally every time it is loaded. Either that or read it from the network into a byte array and load it from memory.